# Bone parents to the wrong end

Tags: armature, bones

I am trying to parent the top of a bone to the bottom of another bone (see image) but when parenting  it will parent to the wrong end,[image] I have tried but was unable to find a way to set it to the other end how can this be fixed?

Comment: You cannot parent joints together, only bones. Parenting top or bottom has no sense, you only parent the whole bone. The line is only a visualisation.